# Javascript - FirebaseClould Issues: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
        // Get a new write batch
        const batch = writeBatch(db);
        var TransactionRecordRef = doc(collection(db, "TopUpRecord"));
        batch.set(TransactionRecordRef, {
            Amount: FinalTopUpAmount,
            DateTime: serverTimestamp(),
            StudentID: StudentID,
        });


        //var TopUptoUserRef = doc(collection(db, "user"));

        const UQuery = query(collection(db, "user"), where("studentID", "==", StudentID));
        batch.update(UQuery, { "studentAmount": increment(FinalTopUpAmount) });

        batch.commit();
```

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.8.1): AsyncQueue Failed to persist write: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

[image]

I would like to use writebatch to update the studentAmount Field which searches based on the studentID but it keeps on popping up an error message @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.8.1): AsyncQueue Failed to persist write: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path'). Does anyone know why this kind of issue and is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reviewing your code above, you only queried the document(s) which lacks execution of the query. You need to call the `getDocs` method to retrieve the documents. See sample code below:

```
import { getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

// Get a new write batch
const batch = writeBatch(db);
var TransactionRecordRef = doc(collection(db, "TopUpRecord"));
batch.set(TransactionRecordRef, {
    Amount: FinalTopUpAmount,
    DateTime: serverTimestamp(),
    StudentID: StudentID,
});


//var TopUptoUserRef = doc(collection(db, "user"));

const UQuery = query(collection(db, "user"), where("studentID", "==", StudentID));

// Get the documents from `Uquery`
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(UQuery);
// Loop all the retrieved documents
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // Get the document reference by using `doc.ref`
  batch.update(doc.ref, { "studentAmount": increment(FinalTopUpAmount) });
});

batch.commit();
```

Added some comments on the above code.
For more information, you may check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).